# Is $\{n\log n \pmod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ dense in $[0,1]?$ If so, is it uniformly distributed?

Tags: real-analysis, equidistribution

It is clear that $\{\log n\pmod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ [is dense in $[0,1]$ but not uniformly distributed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580112/log-n-n-in-mathbfn-not-uniformly-distributed-mod-1)

> How about $\{n\log n \pmod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \} ?$ Is it dense in
> $[0,1]?$ If so, is it uniformly distributed?

Definition of uniformly distributed sequence, i.e., equidistributed sequence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Kuipers and Neidrreiter, after several lemmas, it is proved (page 18, Example 2.8) that for any integer $h\neq 0$,
$$
\left|\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N e^{2\pi i h n \log n}\right|=O\left( \frac{\sqrt{|h|}\log N}{\sqrt{N}}\right).
$$
Together with Weyl's criterion, the sequence $n\log n$ is uniformly distributed modulo $1$.